# Wordpress: Query to show all Custom Post Types and set a Post Type icon for each post instead of Featured Images

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've set up this query to show all Post from certain Custom Post Types but I would like to alter the query and change the featured image to a specific icon that relates to the Post Type instead of the set Featured Images

```
function my_query_by_post_types( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'articles', 'events' ] );
    }
add_action( 'elementor/query/all_post_types', 'my_query_by_post_types' );
```

For example instead of showing the featured images for the events, I'd like to show a calendar Icon for all the posts that appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using WP_Query, In your `front-page.php` you can put this

```
$args = array(
             'post_type' => 'my-cpt'
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

if( is_front_page()){
set_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),int $thumbnail_id );
}

// Shows the featured image of your choice with`$thumbnail_id`

the_post_thumbnail()

endwhile;
```

Get the $thumbnail_id of the image you want to set from "Media Library" and hovering/pressing Edit button .

Comment: Where should i put this? And how do i make it linked to that specific query with the custom id #all_post_types. As i need to display the featured image as icon only on that specific query on the homepage. Basically what I am trying to do is to do that only on the homepage to avoid issues with wrong sized/missing featured images for all the new posts

Comment: Sorry , I thought you need it changed everywhere as you haven't mentioned it in your question.  So how you are setting the homepage ? Do you have a `home.php` or `front-page.php` ?

Comment: I am using Elementor and just set up a page as front page

Comment: Sorry i am helpless   ........ from the next question onwards please be specific .

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the featured image output conditionally

```
function wpdocs_addTitleToThumbnail( $html,$post_id ) {
if ( get_post_type($post_id) === 'events' ) 
{
  $html = '<img src="your_img_src"/>';
  return $html;
}


return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpdocs_addTitleToThumbnail' ,10,2);
```

Comment: I'd only need to do that in the specific query